# Error : Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]

Tags: java, filter, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to do external SSO in Alfresco. Done configuratoin in share-config-custom.xml and updated alfrsco-global.properties. Trying to open user dashboard by clicking on a link (URL appended with the alfresco ticket) from another application. Created a Special SSO filter to get the ticket and to set the alfTicket parameter in the connector session.

```
 SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [98] Address already in use
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:433)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)

May 28, 2013 6:16:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [98] Address already in use
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:433)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    ... 13 more
```

Why this error is coming?
After clicking on the link from another application, i could see that my filter is executing, but SSO not happened.

Comment: You appear to have something already listing on port 8080, so tomcat can't claim it. Did you try checking what that was, and stopping it?

Comment: Yes. I got it. I stopped the process and tried.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried with changing the port number 8080 initially assigned. Change the same by doing the following steps:
Edit server.xml present in folder conf/ :
Replace the code below -

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

with code:

```
 <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Then try running. This worked for me.